# Create list item trough workflow fired by another list

Tags: discussion-board, workflow-activity

I'm using SPD 2013, but the workflows are from 2010 version.

I wrote a workflow meant to add a new item to a Discussion List. This workflow is started when another list is edited. For instance, when an item on **List A** have its status changed from *"Draft"* to *"Published"*, a new discussion is created in **List B**.

When I edit the item in List A, the workflow is fired but does not add the new Discussion to List B. I get the following message:

**Coercion Failed: Unable to transform the input lookup data into the requested type**

Have anyone faced this before? How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance,
Tiago

Comment: may be a type problem like in https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ac6913c4-396b-4e7c-a42f-ee78656c7532/coercion-failed-unable-to-transform-the-input-lookup-data-into-the-requested-type?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious  ?